# Ansible for Windows: test group membership

Tags: windows, ansible

Using Ansible 2.2.1, I need to test group membership for a given user.

```
  - name : get users details
    win_user:
      name: "{{ myUser }}"
      state: query
    register: userData

  - debug:
      msg: "userData.groups : {{ userData.groups }}"
```

Now I'd like to test whether or not myUser belongs to "myGroup" (with `myGroup="Administrators"` for instance) within a `when` condition.
The `userData.groups` is:

> ok: [test-machine] => { "msg": "userData.groups : [{u'path': u'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Administrators', u'name': u'Administrators'}, {u'path': u'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Performance Monitor Users', u'name': u'Performance Monitor Users'}]"}

So here we see that my user belongs to two groups: "Administrators" and "Performance Monitor Users".

How to write a when statement to test if the user belongs to a particular group?

I've tried some combinations of `with_elements`, `with_dict` without success so far.

Comment: Anything successful here ? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_user_module.html

Comment: I can help you if you provide the output to the debug task. (I don't have a windows host with ansible installed)

Comment: Here we go :
`ok: [test-machine] => {
    "msg": "userData.groups : [{u'path': u'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Administrators', u'name': u'Administrators'}, {u'path': u'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Performance Monitor Users', u'name': u'Performance Monitor Users'}]"}`
So here we see that my user belongs to two groups : `Administrators` and `Performance Monitor Users`
So how to write a `when` statement to test if the user belongs to a particular group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#map) to extract a list of groups for the account and test the membership with `in` operator:

```
- debug:
    msg: "membership confirmed"
  when: "'Administrators' in (userData.groups | map(attribute='name') | list)"
```

If you replace the string `Administrators` with the `myGroup` variable, there is no need for the wrapping quotes:

```
- debug:
    msg: "membership confirmed"
  when: myGroup in (userData.groups | map(attribute='name') | list)
  vars:
    myGroup: Administrators
```

---

An alternative way (a bit less clear than the above), would be to use [`selectattr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#selectattr) with [`search` or `match` filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) and check if the resulting list was not empty. The filters would allow for partial matches (`search`) or regular expressions (`match`). For example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "membership confirmed"
  when: userData.groups | selectattr('name', 'matches', 'Dom.*Adm.*') | list | length > 0
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    groupdict:
      - name: 'Administrators'
        path: 'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Administrators'
      - name: 'Performance Monitor Users'
        path: 'WinNT://WORKGROUP/TEST-MACHINE/Performance Monitor Users'

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ groupdict }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "is admin"
      with_items: "{{ groupdict }}"
      when: item.name == "Administrators"
```

Since I don't often use windows, I just created a variable instead. basically you want to iterate the list: `with_items: "{{ userData.groups }}"` then you want to match like this: `when: item.name == "Administrators"`. You can also substitute "Administrators" with a variable

Comment: The exemple  is working, but I was not able to adapt it to my situation.